# Port forwarding isn't working on raspberry pi

Tags: port-forwarding, owncloud

WAN port: 54321
LAN port:443
LAN IP address: 192.168.1.3
Protocol: both
Status: on
part of /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
    upstream php-handler {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 154.103.X.X;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  # enforce https
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 154.103.X.X;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;
    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www/owncloud;
    client_max_body_size 1000M; # set max upload size
}
```

And part of /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php file:

```
    <?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'updatechecker' => false,
  'instanceid' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'passwordsalt' => 'EzM1WXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'ePDc6YbtXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => '192.168.1.3',
    1 => '154.103.X.X',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/media/owncloud',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://154.103.X.X',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '9.1.6.2',
  'dbname' => 'root',
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" is not a good problem statement. Are you trying to connect to https://154.103.X.X:54321 ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to access Owncloud on Raspberry pi from the Internet.

Comment: Whan software are you using for port forwarding? `iptables`?